# How to get all combinations of several letters in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I get all combinations of several letters in python 3 without using itertools? For example, we have a,b,c, how do we get all possible combinations including `a,b,c,ab,ba,ac,ca,bc,cb,abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is equal to following functions which is a pyhtoinic way to go for calculating the combinations :

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

If you don't want to import the `itertools` module you can use this function.